# Oracle 12.2.0.4 and JDK 1.6.0_45

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, jdk6

We're upgrading the database of an application which is on jdk 1.6. 
Is there any way to connect 1.6 app with oracle 12.2.0.4?

As I could see on official oracle site, the only version of ojdbc that 12.2.0.4 supports is ojdbc8 which requires jdk 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant "12.2.0.1" as I don't think "12.2.0.4" exists. Unless you have "11.2.0.4" in mind? Anyway you don't have to upgrade the JDBC driver. You can continue to use the old JDBC driver that supports JDK6. The "12.2.0.2" server will be compatible with the JDBC driver from "11.2" ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA

Could you explain it to me? I see the line :
"In Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1), Oracle JDBC drivers no longer support JDK 6 or earlier versions."

My mistake i had 12.2.0.1 on my mind :)

Comment: If you upgrade the JDBC driver to 12.2.0.1 then yes you have to upgrade your JDK to 8 or later. But it's not because you upgrade the database that you have to upgrade the JDBC driver. You can continue to use the JDBC driver from 11.2 if that's what you're using. You will miss some of the new features such as Sharding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a Java 6 application will work with a 12c database. You can carry on using the existing ojdbc jar and it will work. I think what you're referring to might be something else.

Comment: Could you look at the commet that i replied to Jean de Lavarene?
How do you understand that?

Comment: @AleksanderNuszel it says "Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1) JDBC drivers are certified with supported Oracle Database releases (11.x.0.x). However, they are not certified to work with older, unsupported database releases, such as 10.2.x, 10.1.x, 9.2.x, and 9.0.1.x."

I think the keyword is "certified", the old driver will work but Oracle will probably just refuse to look at any bugs that are raised.